# Why can't I position this <a> over the following div?

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with positioning. There is container div which contains another div and a tag inside (both separately) I need a tag to be over the second div, but it doesn't seem to work when I use z-index:

Here is jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7YQhu/

and code

```
.container{
    width: 100%; 
    background: yellow; 
    opacity: 0.4; 
    height: 130px;
    position:absolute;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.5;  
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.inner-link {
    margin:15px auto;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;

    z-index: 99!important;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a stacking context for the `<a>` by giving it a position value other than the default, `static`

```
.inner-link {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/7YQhu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Set `.inner-link` to also have `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0):

Add  position: relative; to inner-link class.